# Value of In-Memory DB for a use case without hot partition problem

Tags: redis, amazon-dynamodb, storage, latency, in-memory-database

While DynamoDB has millisecond latency (6ms ~ 10ms if partition scheme is designed properly), and In-memory DB will offer microsecond latency. Essentially moving to in-memory DB would remove 10ms from our overall latency.

If network + compute latency is 30ms, and DB fetch is 10ms, total of 40ms, how much value does in-memory DB bring if the overall latency goes from 40ms to 30ms for a service that needs to be as low latency as possible?

From my research in-memory is best used when there is a large read requests on a single partition key in order to solve hot-partition problems. We will have large number of read requests, but if we don't have a hot partition problem and requests will be distributed evenly throughout different partition keys, does an in-memory DB not bring that much value other than the 10ms savings in latency?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like you state, in memory databases are best when massive amounts of reads are pointed to a single partition or key. DynamoDB would limit strongly consistent reads to 3000 per second.

If you can tolerate the small latency increase a database like DynamoDB would be much more beneficial, being serverless and HTTP based means it's really easy to develop with.